# What's the state of the art in email validation for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email

What are you using to validate users' email addresses, and why?

I had been using [`validates_email_veracity_of`](https://github.com/Empact/validates_email_veracity_of) which actually queries the MX servers. But that is full of fail for various reasons, mostly related to network traffic and reliability.

I looked around and I couldn't find anything obvious that a lot of people are using to perform a sanity check on an email address. Is there a maintained, reasonably accurate plugin or gem for this?

P.S.: Please don't tell me to send an email with a link to see if the email works. I'm developing a "send to a friend" feature, so this isn't practical.

Comment: Here is a super-easy way, without dealing with regex: [detecting-a-valid-email-address](http://lindsaar.net/2008/4/14/tip-4-detecting-a-valid-email-address)

Comment: Could you give a more detailed reason why querying MX server is fail? I would like to know so I can see if these are fixable.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With Rails 3.0 you can use a email validation without regexp using the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail).

Here is [my implementation](http://my.rails-royce.org/2010/07/21/email-validation-in-ruby-on-rails-without-regexp/) ([packaged as a gem](https://github.com/hallelujah/valid_email)).

Comment: looks like `###@domain.com` will validate?

Comment: Guys I would like to revive this gem, I did not have time to maintain it. But it seems people still use it and look for improvements. If you are interested, please write me on the github project : hallelujah/valid_email

Answer (score 107):

Don't make this harder than it needs to be.  Your feature is non-critical; validation's just a basic sanity step to catch typos.  I would do it with a simple regex, and not waste the CPU cycles on anything too complicated:

```
/\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/
```

That was adapted from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html -- which you should read if you really want to know all the tradeoffs.  If you want a more correct and much more complicated fully RFC822-compliant regex, that's on that page too.  But the thing is this: *you don't have to get it totally right.*

If the address passes validation, you're going to send an email.  If the email fails, you're going to get an error message.  At which point you can tell the user *"Sorry, your friend didn't receive that, would you like to try again?"* or flag it for manual review, or just ignore it, or whatever.

These are the same options you'd have to deal with if the address *did* pass validation.  Because even if your validation is perfect and you acquire absolute proof that the address exists, sending could still fail.

The cost of a false positive on validation is low.  The benefit of better validation is also low.  Validate generously, and worry about errors when they happen.

Comment: Err, won't that barf on .museum and the new international TLDs? This regex would *prevent* many valid email addresses.

Comment: Agreed with Elijah, this is a bad recommendation. Additionally, I'm not sure how you think you can tell the user that his friend didn't receive the email because there is no way to tell if the email succeeded right off the bat.

Comment: Good point on **.museum** and such -- when I first posted that answer in 2009 it wasn't an issue. I altered the regex. If you have further improvements, you can edit it too, or make this a community wiki post.

Comment: Jaryl: There's no way to know _for sure_ if it succeeded or failed, but many failures will send back a bounce message, and you can set up your mail service to tell you about them.  You can then make the appropriate notifications to the user or to whomever else ought to know.

Comment: This is exactly the regex I was looking for. At the end of the day as SFEley pointed out, the only thing the validation needs to do is to help the user realise if they forgot to put in an email or entered their name or similar by mistake. If they want to give you an invalid email they will.

Comment: FYI, this will still miss some valid email addresses.  Not many, but a few.  For instance, technically #|@foo.com is a valid email address, as is "Hey I can have spaces if they're quoted"@foo.com.  I find it easiest to just ignore anything before the @ and validate just the domain part.

Comment: I agree with the motivation that you should not worry about allowing through some incorrect addresses. Sadly this regex will disallow some correct addresses, which I view as unacceptable. Perhaps something like this would be better? /.+@.+\..+/

Comment: Building on the above, put this in your model: `validates :email_field, :format => { :with => /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/, :message => "Email address not valid" }, :allow_blank=>false`

Comment: yeah i think the regex as just an example to build upon for your custom needs this works nice for other languages too thanks!

Comment: to allow coma-separated emails: `\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+(,[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+)*\z`

Comment: `validates_format_of :email, with: /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/` combined with a dns domain blacklist, captcha and actual email confirmation

Comment: My ultimate email validator: `/\A\S+@\S+\.\S+\z/`

Answer (score 12):

I created a gem for email validation in Rails 3. I'm kinda surprised that Rails doesn't include something like this by default.

http://github.com/balexand/email_validator

Comment: This is essentially a wrapper around the regex.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use this with an `if` or `unless` statement? Documentation seems sparse.

Comment: @cwd I think the documentation is complete. If you're not familiar with Rails 3+ validations, then check out this Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3) or http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Answer (score 10):

This project seems to have the most watchers on github at the moment (for email validation in rails):

https://github.com/alexdunae/validates_email_format_of

Answer (score 7):

From the [Rails 4 docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators):

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "is not an email")
    end
  end
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
end
```

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4 simply add `validates :email, email:true` (assuming your field is called `email`) to your model and then write a simple (or complex†) `EmailValidator` to suit your needs.

eg: - your model:

```
class TestUser
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email,     type: String
  validates :email, email: true
end
```

Your validator (goes in `app/validators/email_validator.rb`)

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_QTEXT           = Regexp.new '[^\\x0d\\x22\\x5c\\x80-\\xff]', nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_DTEXT           = Regexp.new '[^\\x0d\\x5b-\\x5d\\x80-\\xff]', nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_ATOM            = Regexp.new '[^\\x00-\\x20\\x22\\x28\\x29\\x2c\\x2e\\x3a-\\x3c\\x3e\\x40\\x5b-\\x5d\\x7f-\\xff]+', nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_QUOTED_PAIR     = Regexp.new '\\x5c[\\x00-\\x7f]', nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN_LITERAL  = Regexp.new "\\x5b(?:#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_DTEXT}|#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_QUOTED_PAIR})*\\x5d", nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_QUOTED_STRING   = Regexp.new "\\x22(?:#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_QTEXT}|#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_QUOTED_PAIR})*\\x22", nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN_REF      = EMAIL_ADDRESS_ATOM
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_SUB_DOMAIN      = "(?:#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN_REF}|#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN_LITERAL})"
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_WORD            = "(?:#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_ATOM}|#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_QUOTED_STRING})"
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN          = "#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_SUB_DOMAIN}(?:\\x2e#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_SUB_DOMAIN})*"
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_LOCAL_PART      = "#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_WORD}(?:\\x2e#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_WORD})*"
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_SPEC            = "#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_LOCAL_PART}\\x40#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_DOMAIN}"
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN         = Regexp.new "#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_SPEC}", nil, 'n'
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_EXACT_PATTERN   = Regexp.new "\\A#{EMAIL_ADDRESS_SPEC}\\z", nil, 'n'

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ EMAIL_ADDRESS_EXACT_PATTERN
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'is not a valid email')
    end
  end
end
```

This will allow all sorts of valid emails, including *tagged* emails like "test+no_really@test.tes" and so on.

To test this with `rspec` in your `spec/validators/email_validator_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "EmailValidator" do
  let(:validator) { EmailValidator.new({attributes: [:email]}) }
  let(:model) { double('model') }

  before :each do
    model.stub("errors").and_return([])
    model.errors.stub('[]').and_return({})  
    model.errors[].stub('<<')
  end

  context "given an invalid email address" do
    let(:invalid_email) { 'test test tes' }
    it "is rejected as invalid" do
      model.errors[].should_receive('<<')
      validator.validate_each(model, "email", invalid_email)
    end  
  end

  context "given a simple valid address" do
    let(:valid_simple_email) { 'test@test.tes' }
    it "is accepted as valid" do
      model.errors[].should_not_receive('<<')    
      validator.validate_each(model, "email", valid_simple_email)
    end
  end

  context "given a valid tagged address" do
    let(:valid_tagged_email) { 'test+thingo@test.tes' }
    it "is accepted as valid" do
      model.errors[].should_not_receive('<<')    
      validator.validate_each(model, "email", valid_tagged_email)
    end
  end
end
```

This is how I've done it anyway. YMMV

†Regular expressions are like violence; if they don't work you are not using enough of them.

Comment: I'm tempted to use your validation, but I have no idea where you got it from or how you made it. Can you tell us?

Comment: I got the regular expression from a google search, and wrote the wrapper code and spec tests myself.

Comment: Its great that you posted the tests as well! But what really got me was the power-quote up there! :)

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 3 it's possible to write a **reusable** validator, as this great post explains:

http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/11/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-independent-model-validators

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveRecord::Validator   
  def validate()
    record.errors[:email] << "is not valid" unless
    record.email =~ /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i   
  end
end
```

and use it with `validates_with`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  validates_with EmailValidator
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As [Hallelujah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555303/17174) suggests I think using the [Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail/) is a good approach. However, I dislike some of the hoops there.

I use:

```
def self.is_valid?(email) 

  parser = Mail::RFC2822Parser.new
  parser.root = :addr_spec
  result = parser.parse(email)

  # Don't allow for a TLD by itself list (sam@localhost)
  # The Grammar is: (local_part "@" domain) / local_part ... discard latter
  result && 
     result.respond_to?(:domain) && 
     result.domain.dot_atom_text.elements.size > 1
end
```

You could be stricter by demanding that the TLDs (top level domains) are in [this list](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt), however you would be forced to update that list as new TLDs pop up (like the 2012 addition `.mobi` and `.tel`)

The advantage of hooking the parser direct is that the [rules in Mail grammar](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/parsers/rfc2822.treetop) are fairly wide for the portions the Mail gem uses, it is designed to allow it to parse an address like `user<user@example.com>` which is common for SMTP. By consuming it from the `Mail::Address` you are forced to do a bunch of extra checks.

Another note regarding the Mail gem, even though the class is called RFC2822, the grammar has some elements of [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), for example [this test](https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/b6c5d4d96373fd02754f257cfc27b12f75c9e97f).

Comment: Thanks for this snippet, Sam. I'm a little surprised there is not a generic "good enough most of the time" validation provided by the Mail gem.

Answer (score 3):

Noting the other answers, the question still remains - why bother being clever about it?

The actual volume of edge cases that many regex may deny or miss seems problematic.

I think the question is 'what am I trying to acheive?', even if you 'validate' the email address, you're not actually validating that it is a working email address.

If you go for regexp, just check for the presence of @ on the client side.

As for the incorrect email scenario, have a 'message failed to send' branch to your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 3 most common options:

1. Regexp (there is no works-for-all e-mail address regexp, so roll your own)
2. MX query (that is what you use)
3. Generating an activation token and mailing it (restful_authentication way)

If you don't want to use both validates_email_veracity_of and token generation, I'd go with old school regexp checking.

Answer (score 1):

The Mail gem has a built in address parser.

```
begin
  Mail::Address.new(email)
  #valid
rescue Mail::Field::ParseError => e
  #invalid
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me in Rails 3.1. Mail::Address.new("john") happily returns me a new Mail::Address object, without raising an exception.

Comment: OK, it will throw an exception in some cases, but not all. @Hallelujah's link seems to have a good approach here.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on answers by @SFEley and @Alessandro DS, with a refactor, and usage clarification.

You can use this validator class in your model like so:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates :colum, :email => { :allow_nil => true, :message => 'O hai Mark!' }
  # ...
end
```

Given you have the following in your `app/validators` folder (Rails 3):

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    return options[:allow_nil] == true if value.nil?

    unless matches?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'must be a valid email address')
    end
  end

  def matches?(value)
    return false unless value

    if /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]+\z/.match(value).nil?
      false
    else
      true
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Mailing Lists Validation**. (I use Rails 4.1.6)

I got my regexp from [here](https://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php). It seems to be a very complete one, and it's been tested against a great number of combinations. You can see the results on that page.

I slightly changed it to a Ruby regexp, and put it in my `lib/validators/email_list_validator.rb`

Here's the code:

```
require 'mail'

class EmailListValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  # Regexp source: https://fightingforalostcause.net/content/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php
  EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEXP   = Regexp.new('\A(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))\z', true)

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    begin
      invalid_emails = Mail::AddressList.new(value).addresses.map do |mail_address|
        # check if domain is present and if it passes validation through the regex
        (mail_address.domain.present? && mail_address.address =~ EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEXP) ? nil : mail_address.address
      end

      invalid_emails.uniq!
      invalid_emails.compact!
      record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_emails, :emails => invalid_emails.to_sentence) if invalid_emails.present?
    rescue Mail::Field::ParseError => e

      # Parse error on email field.
      # exception attributes are:
      #   e.element : Kind of element that was wrong (in case of invalid addres it is Mail::AddressListParser)
      #   e.value: mail adresses passed to parser (string)
      #   e.reason: Description of the problem. A message that is not very user friendly
      if e.reason.include?('Expected one of')
        record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_email_list_characters)
      else
        record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_emails_generic)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

And I use it like this in the model:

```
validates :emails, :presence => true, :email_list => true
```

It will validate mailing lists like this one, with different separators and synthax:

```
mail_list = 'John Doe <john@doe.com>, chuck@schuld.dea.th; David G. <david@pink.floyd.division.bell>'
```

Before using this regexp, I used `Devise.email_regexp`, but that is a very simple regexp and didn't get all the cases I needed. Some emails bumped.

I tried other regexps from the web, but this one's got the best results till now. Hope it helps in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It will also validate against mails_lists such as:
`mail_list = 'John Doe <john@doe.com>, chuck@schuld.dea.th; Nedda G. <nedda-current-gold@tiwwmaawnc.co.uk>'`

````
class EmailListValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEXP   = Regexp.new('\A(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\x22?\x5C[\x00-\x7E]\x22?)|(?:\x22?[^\x5C\x22]\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22))(?:\.(?:(?:[\x21\x23-\x27\x2A\x2B\x2D\x2F-\x39\x3D\x3F\x5E-\x7E]+)|(?:\x22(?:[\x01-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7F]|(?:\x5C[\x00-\x7F]))*\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\]))\z', true)

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    begin
      invalid_emails = Mail::AddressList.new(value).addresses.map do |mail_address|
        (mail_address.domain.present? && mail_address.address =~ EMAIL_VALIDATION_REGEXP) ? nil : mail_address.address
      end

      invalid_emails.uniq!
      invalid_emails.compact!
      record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_emails, :emails => invalid_emails.to_sentence) if invalid_emails.present?
    rescue Mail::Field::ParseError => e
      if e.reason.include?('Expected one of')
        record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_email_list_characters)
      else
        record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_emails_generic)
      end
    end
  end

end```
````