# Trying to add validation to rails devise sign-up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Kinda a noob rails programmer, but this would save me a ton of headache. Currently, I'm trying to add validation to my devise sign on page, such as only allowing the sign up to complete if their email ends with a certain extension. Does anyone know where the file location stands that overlooks the sign on page? I've looked over all models and views but can't seem to find it. Thank you!

Comment: You can add a validation to User model, or whichever your devise model is.`app/models`

Comment: See here for email validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156601/whats-the-state-of-the-art-in-email-validation-for-rails

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe it was under my nose the whole time. I can feel the love from the stack community :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use validates_format_of in your user.rb model. You can use rubular.com to create the regex.

```
validates_format_of :email, :with => /MYREGEXHERE/
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add validation to your email field. There is nothing special you have to do. like:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /my_ending_string\z/, message: "must ends with my_ending_string" }
```